# Else If Stament Not Working Properly

Tags: java, if-statement

As you can tell I'm new to this Stack Over Flow. I almost always end up reading post here when I'm programing though. It seems like a pretty good place to be, so I decided to join. Thank you for letting me spam you.

My code was working a few minutes ago. I'm pretty sure it's something stupid that I did on accident. When I enter in a number every menu option except for 7 works. When I enter in 7 in pops up a box saying Invalid option. Using an if statement I deduced that whatToDo actually could equal 7 yet it would still pop up the box.

```
package TB_Game;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TB_Game {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    menu();
}

public static void menu() {

    String whatToDo;
    try {
        whatToDo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welcome to the TextBased Game! " + "\n"
                        + "\n" + "Which game do you wish to play?" + "\n"
                        + "1 - Gangup - Work in Progress" + "\n"
                        + "2 - Black Jack - Not Been Finished" + "\n"
                        + "3 - Encryption - Non GUI" + "\n"
                        + "4 - Decryption - Non GUI" + "\n"
                        + "5 - Encryption GUI" + "\n"
                        + "6 - Decryption GUI" + "\n"
                        + "7 - Alchemy - Work In Progress" + "\n"
                        + "8 - Exit");
        if (whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("Gangup") || whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            gangup.startGangup();
        }
        else if (whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("Black Jack") || whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Black Jack has not been finished",
                    "Text Based Game", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    menu();
        }
        else if (whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("Encryption") || whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
            cryption.encrypt();
        }
        else if (whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("Decryption") || whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
            cryption.decrypt();
        }
        else if (whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("Encryption GUI") || whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("5")) {
            cryptionGUI.encrypt();
        }
        else if (whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("Decryption GUI") || whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("6")) {
            cryptionGUI.decrypt();
        }
        else if (whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("Alchemy") || whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("7")) {
            Alchemy.startAlchemy();
        }
        else if (whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit") || whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("8")) {
            exit();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Option",
                    "Text Based Game", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            menu();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Option",
                "Text Based Game", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        menu();
    }
}

public static void exit() {
    int quit;
    quit = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            "Do you wish to close TB Game?");
    if (quit == 0) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        menu();
    }
}

}
```

The formating is a little messed up because of my copy and pasting into here.

Comment: You should make the message in the`catch` block different from the one in the `else` block so that you can tell them apart. I bet your `startAlchemy()` method is throwing an exception.

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace();` as the first statement in your catch block and run the code.

Comment: Often, avoiding tabs and using only spaces for indentation results in code that can be copy-pasted preserving indentation. That can be useful for getting help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting an exception while executing the code for option 7 :

```
 else if (whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("Alchemy") || whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("7")) {
        Alchemy.startAlchemy();
    }
```

And as per the catch block if there is an exception it will say "Invalid option" while execking the following statement

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Option",
                "Text Based Game", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

So the problem lies in the `Alchemy.startAlchemy()` and not in `else if`. If you encapsulate your code like this it will confirm where the problem is:

```
 else if (whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("Alchemy") || whatToDo.equalsIgnoreCase("7")) {
        try {
        Alchemy.startAlchemy();
        } catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println("The problem is not with else if but the exception");
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow that is some pretty crappy code.

For one, I would do a

```
whatToDo = whatToDo.trim();
```

before doing some comparisons.

Have you tried running in debug or putting a System.out.println to see if there is not something wrong with the Alchemy.startAlchemy() method?

The if/else logic looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

Have you messed up with the Alchemy.startAlchemy code? I guess problem lies there